# Making Array of Objects from mySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, realm

I am trying to return Array of Objects from mySQL database but the array length is returning zero (no items).

I am trying to read from sample MySQL World database tables country and cities. Eventually i will create Realm document in which Country document will hold all its cities.

I am not an expert in asyn/await javascript and struggling in this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
async function **createFile**() {
    listCountry = await fetchData();

    console.log(listCountry.length);
    // createDocuments(listCountry);
}

async function **fetchData**() {
    const countryList = new Array();
    const connection = await mySQLConn;
    const rsCountry = await connection.query('select * from country');

    // fetch country and their cities

    rsCountry.forEach(async country => {
        console.log('Working on ' + country.Code);

        const rsCity = await connection.query(
            "select ID, Name from city where CountryCode='" + country.Code + "'"
        );

        // get the cities
        var cityList = new Array();
        rsCity.forEach(city => {
            // console.log(city);
            cityelem = { id: city.ID, name: city.Name };
            cityList.push(cityelem);
        });

        // push item to array
        countryList.push({
            code: country.Code,
            name: country.Name,
            cities: cityList
        });
    });

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log(countryList.length);
        resolve(countryList);
    });
}
```

Comment: SO is to help with existing code - you've got yours posted but have not indicated what *isn't* working. We need a clear description of your troubleshooting and what line is failing. Your first step is to do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. Then post that result. Additionally, this question, as-is, has nothing to do with Realm so that tag should be removed. Once you implement Realm and run into an issue *then* add a Realm tag to the new question.